# Can I mark a Hard Drive as non-removable?

Tags: windows-10

I have replaced the DVD Drive in my Laptop with a S-ATA Hard Drive, which works well. However, Windows believes that the hard drive is removable and lists it e.g. in the "Safely remove hardware and eject media" popup, or for any applications that show a list of removable drives.

Is there a way to have Windows treat the hard drive like a non-removable/fixed drive?

Comment: In device manager (win XP) right click on that drive -> Properties -> Policies: tick "Optimized for performance". I do not have win10 cannot check if that option exits in win10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested on Windows 10 with the standard issue Microsoft issued chipset.

- Launch "regedit".
- Under
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\Parameters\Device`,
  create a new `REG_MULTI_SZ`. Label it `TreatAsInternalPort`.
- In the "Values" box, enter the port values which you would like to
  mark as non-removable, i.e. *enter '0' for port '0'*

[image]

I believe this setting is also dependent on your chipset/drive controller. As such, a different chipset maker might have a different registry entry for this configuration.

Comment: Might want to add whichchipset you tested that with.

Comment: Indeed, this won't work for Intel's iaStorA, but it works for standard Microsoft storahci. Thanks!

Comment: How do I find out which port number corresponds to a disk?