# Can I mark a hard drive as removable (storahci service)?

Tags: windows-10, sata, ahci

Basically, I need the [opposite of last time](https://superuser.com/questions/1127994/can-i-mark-a-hard-drive-as-non-removable): I have an internal SATA Port that is connected to a "dock" which allows removing the drive.

I would like the drive to show up in the "Safely remove devices", like a USB Drive would. I confirmed that I'm using the `storahci` service, but I haven't found an option that's the opposite of `TreatAsInternalPort`.

I've tried `TreatAsExternalPort` without success. I've disabled write caching on the drive, and confirmed that AHCI Mode is enabled in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I use hotswap exe quickk and easy download from  http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm